# How do I get the shadow color value of some text in Fabric JS?

Tags: fabricjs

I can't seem to find any reference in the Fabric.js docs (or anywhere else) on how to get the shadow color value of some text placed on the canvas?

I'm quite new to Fabric.js.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to get the rgb values of a text shadow color:

```
...
var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();
var shadColor = activeObject.shadow.color;
var shadProps = shadColor.split(",");

var r = shadProps[0];
r = r.replace("rgb(", "");

var g = shadProps[1];

var b = shadProps[2];
b = b.replace(")", "");

console.log('Red: '+r+'   Green: '+g+'   Blue: '+b);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have a reference to the fabric object it's located at: `fabricObject.shadow.color`

Comment: Thank you so much for that answer.